# Opposite of "wrap selection with tag" in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a smarter way of removing the tag (let's say using HTML) around a selection in Sublime text 2?
For example if I have a `span` tag around some text and want to remove both the start and end of this tag (and leave the text inside untouched)...
Or alternative - remove current tag and it's corresponding end tag?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) plugin (once called Zen Coding) can do what you want. [Install](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#how-to-install) it and press `Ctrl+Shift+;` within a tag's contents to unwrap the tag.

Comment: Wow nice! -- FYI on Mac the shortcut is CMD+'

Answer (score 0):

A bit easier way to do this is to use a macro:

`unwrap.sublime-macro`

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "to": "tag"
        },
        "command": "expand_selection"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "copy"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "to": "tag"
        },
        "command": "expand_selection"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "paste_and_indent"
    }
]
```

...with a *ctrl+u* for example:

```
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+u"],
    "command": "run_macro_file", 
    "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/unwrap.sublime-macro"}
}
```

Pros: no plugins required, only default ST functionality. Cons: modifies clipboard data.